# how to catch ECONNREFUSED in a javascript TCP client

Tags: javascript

I have a simple TCP client. It makes a connection to a local data processing server. Sometimes the server will not be running, and that is ok. If it cannot connect, I would like it to fail gracefully with perhaps some console output, but not crash my process.

here is the code:

```
class EngineSwitchboard {

static routePacket(packet) {
    if (gpsPackets.includes(packet.packetId)){
        const gpsClient = new net.Socket();
        gpsClient.connect(9998, 'localhost', function() {
            gpsClient.write(JSON.stringify(packet));
        })

    }
}

}
```

I have tried to wrap it in a try-catch but it still crashes out the calling process with Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9998

thanks for any help

Comment: can you add the on errror handler and try? gpsClient.on('error', function(){})

Comment: that totally worked. thanks so much !

Comment: No problem.Just to close this question. I have added the same as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the socket's on error event handler.

**gpsClient.on('error', function(){})**

The above one is a much generic event handler. If you want to handle specific errors. You can go through the list available and use the appropriate one

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99